# Adobe Flex AIR - detect shift key already down?

Tags: apache-flex, air, key, app-startup

I want to allow a user to override the persistent configuration flags to automatically start and automatically close when complete. One idiom is to detect the Shift key down on startup.

How can I detect the shift key down?

I tried adding a keyboard-down event handler in application initialization, but that did not seem to get called at all.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.  This sentence in particular "to override the persistent configuration flags to automatically start and automatically close when complete"  What is a persistent configuration flag?  What do you want to automatically start or close?  I would expect the shift key to trigger a key down event; but without seeing how you setup your listener; it's tough to diagnose what may have went wrong.

Comment: Are you asking how do you detect if the shift key is down when the key is pressed before you app has even had time to register a keydown listener?

Comment: I'm asking to detect that the shift key is or is not down as the application starts. As long as I can abort actions that it will perform (currently in creationComplete) based on persistent configuration

Comment: You can try to listen for something like mouse over event. If your app is fullscreen, then it's likely to happen. However, you can always use native extensions or native processes to use some native code.